# Can Java Annotations be used for creating a plugin design?

Tags: java, annotations

I have the following situation :

Base Jar file with a class file that can be extended, the use of the class file is to be able to load objects of that type from a file.

Example

Class file that can be extended = Shape

.square files are used to load a Square shape class, .circle files are used to load a Circle shape class etc. It could also be the case that .triangle files can load either an IsoscelesTriangle shape class or an EquilateralTriangle shape class, the first 3 bytes of the file could be an identifier to specify which triangle. The basics is each Shape class determines what criteria it is used to determine whether the file is used to load it or not.

I'd like to be able to have another jar file provided at run time to add the ability for them to process Shape classes that they have defined (one or more shape classes, doesan't matter). The loader would some how find out about these classes or have then registered with itself. I like the idea of the loader class finding out about the new Shape classes in an automated way. Is there a way this can be done at run time with Annotations?

Lastly is there a better way than using Annotations? This is effectively a plugin type architecture and I would prefer not using OSGI

Comment: Well yes. What's stopping you from trying it out? It should not be that much code to set up a simple base for this - and see there it leads you.

Comment: maybe using a Service Provider, check the [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class (not related to Annotations) (or the [Introduction to the Service Provider Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html))